# Reading in numbers from a file into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, file, root-framework

So I have a file with three columns in e.g:

```
1 1 750
```

These are x,y,intensity values.

Then I try to read in this long file into arrays. This is the code so far:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

string fOutFileName("gaintest.root"); 


int main()
{

  std::ifstream file1("data_p30.dat");

  double intensity;
  int i;
  int j ;
  double c[1000][1000];
if (file1.is_open()) {
    file1.seekg(0);
    while (!file1.eof()) {
      file1 >> i >> j >> intensity;
      c[i][j]=intensity;
      cout<<c[i][j]<<'/n'; 
    }
    file1.close();
  } else cout << "Error, cannot open file 1";
}
```

So ultimately I want to be able to have a 2D array that is linked to the intensity. Any ideas on why I am failing? It compiles fine but when it run, it looks like this:

```
root [0] 
 *** Break *** segmentation violation



===========================================================
There was a crash.
This is the entire stack trace of all threads:
===========================================================
#0  0x0000003701098c05 in waitpid () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000370103c481 in do_system () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00002b036f5ebc6a in TUnixSystem::StackTrace() ()
   from /batchsoft/root/root528-x86_64-slc5-43/lib/libCore.so
#3  0x00002b036f5eb63c in TUnixSystem::DispatchSignals(ESignals) ()
   from /batchsoft/root/root528-x86_64-slc5-43/lib/libCore.so
#4  <signal handler called>
#5  0x00002b0370acd515 in TRint::Run(bool) ()
   from /batchsoft/root/root528-x86_64-slc5-43/lib/libRint.so
#6  0x000000000040106d in main ()
===========================================================


The lines below might hint at the cause of the crash.
If they do not help you then please submit a bug report at
http://root.cern.ch/bugs. Please post the ENTIRE stack trace
from above as an attachment in addition to anything else
that might help us fixing this issue.
===========================================================
#5  0x00002b0370acd515 in TRint::Run(bool) ()
   from /batchsoft/root/root528-x86_64-slc5-43/lib/libRint.so
#6  0x000000000040106d in main ()
===========================================================
```

Comment: use an actual matrix type rather than `double[][]` like those provided by boost uBlas and NT2

Comment: `double c[1000,1000];` That is valid C++, but it totally does not do what you think it does.

Comment: The error might make no sense to *you* but it would be very helpful for us.

Comment: That's not the actual code

Comment: OK so I've added the full code in (though I don't see how having my TH2D really helps at the moment since I'm not drawing). It should just start spitting out the intensity values on my screen but it doesn't.

Comment: You don't need to post all the code. I meant that the code you'd posted had errors and wouldn't even compile. I don't like trying to spot errors in code which isn't real. Pare it down. Test it with a `istringstream` instead of a file. Take control.

Comment: OK tried that and it still comes up with the same error as above. Despite compiling fine.

Comment: The code previously wouldn't compile. There were missing curly-braces. Yes, control the environment. Eliminate potential problems. Delete code until you have the thing causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: I just tried istringstream in a simple case of just printing out a number with it and got the exact same error. I think then that root just cannot use it.

Comment: How are you compiling this? Are you using g++ (or something similar), or are you using ROOT to compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++

```
double c[1000, 1000];
```

The first 1000 is thrown away and the compiler generates code for:

```
double c[1000];
```

What you wrote [1000, 1000] is a multi-dimensional array in Pascal, but not in C++.  In C++ you would use:

```
double c[1000][1000];
```

Comment: OK so I changed it to that and added the error in I receive above

Comment: No, you would use that in C. You would use `array<array<double, 1000>, 1000>` in C++

Comment: Hmmm but I just built an array using egarray[][] and it worked for root. I don't think the problem lies there anymore.

Comment: The other problems is that '/n' is a multi-byte character.  Try '\n' instead (or std::endl).

Comment: And if you want to remove the repeated last line:
    i = -1;
    file1 >> i >> j >> intensity;
    if( i == -1 ) break;

Answer (score 0):

The errors you have displayed are generated by ROOT.  Since this is not a ROOT forum, ROOT is a c++ data analysis framework developed by scientists at CERN.  For the curious, their website is [here](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/).  Your problem however, is not related to ROOT.

2D arrays are declared by

```
double a[2][2];
```

and this will work for you.

Perhaps more safe is to use the template class

```
std::vector<double> v;
```

For a 2D application this would look like

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > v2;
```

The advantage of this is that its size can be adjusted as needed and

```
v.push_back(d);
```

will add an element to the end of the vector, elongating it if necessary.  Elements can also be accessed with array syntax like

```
v[1]
```

or

```
v2[1][2]
```